# youtube xml transcript file is not valid

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, youtube-api

I tried this code to load a youtube video transcript file

```
var rqst=$.ajax( {
    dataType : 'jsonp', 
    type : 'GET', 
    url : 'https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=bwOhfoewMYs&lang=en&callback=alert', 

   success : function(response) {
alert("SUCCESS");
             }, 
   error : function() {
       alert("failed."); }
   }
);
```

and this error appears

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

and the variable `rqst` not assigned, so I can't access the file's RespondText 
screenShot:
[image: the error]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read an XML file as JSONP.
That's completely impossible.

Comment: I tried "xml" but I got this error<br>
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=bwOhfoewMYs&lang=en&callback=alert. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: @Amged: You can't read XML from a remote domain either.  You need to either find a JSONP API or use server-side code.